How to apply larger memory for Valgrind
I use Valgrind to check memleak in my project -- a trading system server. When the memory database size configured on the server is large (64G or more), valgrind will exit when I start detecting.
How to apply larger memory for Valgrind? Is there any option could set larger memory for Valgrind?

How much memory do you have in your system? Valgrind likely needs extra memory to keep track of allocations

Quote from https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html: "Each byte in memory has 8 associated V (valid-value) bits  heavy use of compression means the overhead is typically around 25%."

What message do you get? You can increase the stack size via a command line option. If you are running out of segments you will need to rebuild Valgrind.
